# How to make jquery actions wait until another function has completed, all inside same click function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying have user input some data, use ajax to post it and after that use that info to create objects dynamically, but my if statement isn't working. I need the code to be under click function because of many `$(this)` targeting inside the code I'm trying to fire after ajax post.

```
 $(document).on('click' , ".addition" , function(event) {

    $(".submitfolder").click(function() {
     var data3 = $("#form2 :input").serialize();
     var data4 = $("#form2 :input").val();
     nameforfolder = data4;

       $.ajax({
         url: "userfolders.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: data3,
         success: function() {
         var asd = 1;
         }
      });

   if (asd > 0) {
      //do stuff that needs data4.

   } else {        
      //something

   }
 });
```

Comment: partial dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in your function on success, you declare a new variable asd that will be only visible in that function. So you should declare asd in your first function and then just change it in your second function.

```
  var asd = 0;
  $(".submitfolder").click(function() {
         var data3 = $("#form2 :input").serialize();
         var data4 = $("#form2 :input").val();
         nameforfolder = data4;

           $.ajax({
             url: "userfolders.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: data3,
             success: function() {
             asd = 1;
             }

          });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand that Javascript and AJAX works asynchronously, that means javascript continues to execute next line of code even if the previous line isn't done yet! So your `if (asd > 0)` statement is working with a variable which in time of execution isn't defined. So you have to place that logic in your `success` callback function of `$.ajax` call.

And if you're worried about `$(this)`, just use a well-known common hack

```
var _this = this;
```

In the end, you should end up with something like this:

```
$(".submitfolder").click(function() {
  ...  
  var _this = this;

  $.ajax({
    url: "userfolders.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data3,
    success: function() {
      var asd = 1;
      if (asd > 0) {
        // instead of $(this).hide()
        $(_this).hide();
      } else {
        // something
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked. Wasn't aware of the var _this = this; hack, very useful!